# Removing items in array that have the same value

Tags: php, arrays

See my following array, i need to be able to remove the items that have the same values (e.g. Primary, Secondary etc.) Is there a way of doing this to the existing array via php or is it easier to do this before items are inserted into the array?

I've seen the array_unique function but not sure if I can use this seen as it's a multi dimensional array?

```
Array
(
    [0] => SelectAttributeTypeOption Object
        (
            [error] => 
            [ID] => 19
            [value] => Primary
            [th] => TextHelper Object
                (
                )

            [displayOrder] => 0
            [usageCount] => 
        )

    [1] => SelectAttributeTypeOption Object
        (
            [error] => 
            [ID] => 20
            [value] => Secondary
            [th] => TextHelper Object
                (
                )

            [displayOrder] => 1
            [usageCount] => 
        )

    [2] => SelectAttributeTypeOption Object
        (
            [error] => 
            [ID] => 20
            [value] => Secondary
            [th] => TextHelper Object
                (
                )

            [displayOrder] => 1
            [usageCount] => 
        )

    [3] => SelectAttributeTypeOption Object
        (
            [error] => 
            [ID] => 21
            [value] => Groups & Families
            [th] => TextHelper Object
                (
                )

            [displayOrder] => 2
            [usageCount] => 
        )

    [4] => SelectAttributeTypeOption Object
        (
            [error] => 
            [ID] => 19
            [value] => Primary
            [th] => TextHelper Object
                (
                )

            [displayOrder] => 0
            [usageCount] => 
        )

    [5] => SelectAttributeTypeOption Object
        (
            [error] => 
            [ID] => 20
            [value] => Secondary
            [th] => TextHelper Object
                (
                )

            [displayOrder] => 1
            [usageCount] => 
        )

    [6] => SelectAttributeTypeOption Object
        (
            [error] => 
            [ID] => 21
            [value] => Groups & Families
            [th] => TextHelper Object
                (
                )

            [displayOrder] => 2
            [usageCount] => 
        )

    [7] => SelectAttributeTypeOption Object
        (
            [error] => 
            [ID] => 22
            [value] => Adults
            [th] => TextHelper Object
                (
                )

            [displayOrder] => 3
            [usageCount] => 
        )

    [8] => SelectAttributeTypeOption Object
        (
            [error] => 
            [ID] => 19
            [value] => Primary
            [th] => TextHelper Object
                (
                )

            [displayOrder] => 0
            [usageCount] => 
        )

    [9] => SelectAttributeTypeOption Object
        (
            [error] => 
            [ID] => 20
            [value] => Secondary
            [th] => TextHelper Object
                (
                )

            [displayOrder] => 1
            [usageCount] => 
        )

    [10] => SelectAttributeTypeOption Object
        (
            [error] => 
            [ID] => 21
            [value] => Groups & Families
            [th] => TextHelper Object
                (
                )

            [displayOrder] => 2
            [usageCount] => 
        )
)
```

Comment: It depends where the data comes from, and how it is added to the array.. If it comes from the DB, you could probably change your query to do so..

Comment: Why not to solve this problem from sql statement, all you need to add is `GROUP BY value`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function:

```
array_filter( $array, function( $elem ) use ( $value ) {   
  return $elem['value'] !== $value; 
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$new = array_reduce(
    $old,
    function ($result, $item) {
        if (!in_array($item, $result)) {
            $result[] = $item;
        }
        return $result;
    }
);
```

But if these objects are fetched from DB, you're better off filtering your result set beforehand with `GROUP BY id` or whatever unique record identifier you have, as Finciuc Sergiu suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```
foreach($array as $row) {
    if(!isset($output[$row['value']])) {
        $output[$row['value']] = $row;
    }
}

//reset array keys if you want //$output = array_values($output)
```